# Somar contador - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query

Possuo a seguinte `Query`:

```
SELECT 
array_to_string(array_agg('"'||public.lotesretornosuprimento.codigoestoque||'"'), ', ') as codigos,
est.codigosuprimento, 
public.suprimento.suprimento,
(
    select count(est02.codigosuprimento) from public.estoque est02 where est02.numeronotafiscal = est.numeronotafiscal and
    est.codigosuprimento = est02.codigosuprimento

) as qtdSuprimento, 
est.codigofornecedor,  
public.fornecedor.nome,
est.numeronotafiscal, 
to_char(est.datanotafiscal, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as datanotafiscal
FROM 
public.estoque est,
public.suprimento,
public.fornecedor,
public.lotesretornosuprimento
where 
public.lotesretornosuprimento.dataretorno between '2018-01-01' and '2019-01-24' and
est.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo and
est.codigosuprimento between 155 and 155 and
est.codigofornecedor = public.fornecedor.codigo and
est.codigofornecedor between 8 and 8 and
public.lotesretornosuprimento.codigoestoque = est.codigo 
group by 
est.codigosuprimento, 
est.codigofornecedor, 
est.numeronotafiscal, 
est.datanotafiscal,
public.suprimento.suprimento,
public.fornecedor.nome 
order by
public.fornecedor.nome,
public.suprimento.suprimento,
est.numeronotafiscal
```

Que dentre **N** itens que me são retornados esta um contador que me mostra a quantidade de determinado suprimento dentro de uma nota, que é essa parte da `Query`:

```
    (select count(est02.codigosuprimento) from public.estoque est02 where est02.numeronotafiscal = est.numeronotafiscal and
est.codigosuprimento = est02.codigosuprimento) as qtdSuprimento
```

Preciso somar esse contador, como poderia realizar isso?

Meu retorno esta assim no momento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia fornecer um exemplo simples de como está o resultado atual da sua consulta e como você gostaria que ficasse, pois, não sei se compreendi bem essa parte de somar o resultado do count.

Comment: @SpockWayne atualizei minha pergunta para mostrar meu retorno como esta até o momento